# Is this possible to use file path instead of filename in open() function for zip in PHP

Tags: php, zip, backup

I've made a program for making a backup, the problem is that it is only working when my script is in the same folder as files I am making a backup of. I need to put this script in folder backup and when I put it there script just shows files, it should backup(as it should) but then the backup is not being made

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('../backup/zip/backup_of_files'.date('d-m-y').'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
     $file_list=array_diff(scandir('/'),array('..','.'));
     foreach($file_list as $file){
                 $new_filename = substr($plik,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
         $zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);    
         echo $file."<br>";
                 $zip->close();
      }
}
```

That's not the full code but I think it will be enough, again code works when in "/" path and it makes a backup of files in this path but when I put this program in "/backup" it only lists files and folders that it should also backup

Comment: Instead of using relative paths, consider setting a constant in the bootstrap of the application that is defined as the path to the folder the bootstrap is in. `define('APP_PATH', dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: I am not using bootstrap but I've changed the relative path to constant but I added an argument to dirname "2" because then it will be a path to the place I want, so thank you anyways :D

Comment: I think the problem is that addFile() needs filename and not the path

Comment: The same script works in a directory where are files I want to backup but when I put it one level down (to folder "backup") and add an argument to dirname "2"  it only lists files it should backup (sorry I am repeating but I just can't get why is this happening)